# Generate email from an user's own mailbox on Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, outlook, power-automate

I have created a workflow via Power Automate to send an email to a list of people when an announcement is created on SharePoint. It works fine if I would like to be the person who appears as a sender of that email. However, this workflow will be used by a few users in another department, and I would like these automated emails be generated with these users who become the sender. At present, if someone else posted an announcement, the automated email will be sent as if I posted it myself. Is there a way for the email to be sent from whoever logged onto Office 365 at the time? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **"From (Send as)"** for emails sending from Power Automate to appear have been sent from the user's account who created the item. However, for that to work, users creating items should have "Delegation" permission on the email account of the user running the flow. You can find more info on that [here](https://www.technologytobusiness.com/microsoft-flow-logic-apps/workflow-not-authorized-account-send-email).

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Is there another way to do this without delegating?  I am hoping the users can run the flow using their own account instead of going through me.

Comment: I'm afraid that you don't have any other option as your flow is triggered when item is created. There's a "Run as" option, but that is applicable for **manually** triggered flow. You can read more about that [here](https://www.serverlessnotes.com/docs/sharing-flows-as-owners-and-run-only-users)